# how to insert enumerations into another one in c++

Tags: c++, enums, enumeration

I am using an enumeration to represent all signals in the system and there   is a base signals which are represented in an enumeration but i want to add other signals to it by calling a function or something like that
can i insert an enumeration in another one?

Comment: Please explain in more detail, if possible with a code sample, what you mean. Right now it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you want to add new enum values to an enum at runtime? This wouldn't be possible nor necessary, as they are compiled to literal integers, so you could just use any other int value for extending you enum

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extending enums in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804840/extending-enums-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

Enum in fact maps an identifier to an integer at compile time. You cannot change it at runtime. But for runtime the analogue will be a `std::map<std::string, int>`, in this case you can add new values at runtime as follows:

```
std::map<std::string, int> values;

// add new values in this way
values.insert( "var1", 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend enumeration per se, certainly not at run time (which is meaningless anyway because `enum` is just a list of literals replacing numerical constants).

If you actually mean that you want to extend the list of the constants used in your code then read on:

What you can do is make another enum which will be "compatible" in this way (or similar):

```
enum {
   E1_ONE,
   E1_TWO,
   E1_LAST,
} base;

enum {
   E1_THREE = E1_LAST,
   E1_FOUR,
   E1_EXT_LAST,
} extension;
```

And use the `enum extension` type in your code where you handle your new values, but the `enum base` type in the legacy code that you're extending.

`enum` is basically an integer with restricted values, so you'll have to verify limits etc.

If you have the access to the original source code (which I assume you do...) it would be better to change the original enum, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your recent reply, my guess is that you want to have a list of enum codes, and you want to modify that list at will?

If this is the case, then just create a list/vector/set of *int*. This will hold your values, independently of your enum type (as all enums are initialized with a hidden integer value). You can then add/remove items from this list at will.

Example:

```
enum SignalsA {
        X,
        Y,
        Z
};

enum SignalsB {
        A,
        B,
        C
};

int main(){

        std::set<int> signal_set;

        signal_set.insert(Z); //Insert enum value from SignalsA
        signal_set.insert(A); //Insert enum value from SignalsB
}
```

Comment: i think this would help in my code , thank you :)
but i have one question what is set<int> as i want to make the last two lines in a separate function not in main function

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question. Are you asking what set<int> is? Set is an associative container, in which you can store several types, and access them by their value. The documentation is here: 

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/

You can make separate functions that receive a std::set<int>& and an int, and then just insert that int to the set<int> list in the function arguments.

Comment: i want to accesss both enum in another function not the main one

Comment: You can create a function(std::set<int>& signal_list, int enum_value) and insert the values in separate functions. Or you can create a more specific function(std::set<int>& signal_list, SignalsA enum_value)

Comment: Glad I could help :) If it solved your problem could you accept the answer? This way, future people with the same problem can solve it more easily.