# Adding values to a C++ enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Suppose I have the following code *in another library that I can't change*:

```
typedef enum {
    p0  = 0,
    p1  = 1,
    p2  = 2,
    p3  = 3,
    p4  = 4,
    p5  = 5,
    p6  = 6,
    ...
} PinName;
```

I want to add some extra aliases like this (*not using `const PinName PIN_...`*):

```
enum class : PinName {
    PIN_SD_MOSI = p0,
    PIN_SD_MISO = p4,
    PIN_SD_SCK = p2,
    PIN_SD_CSN = p6,
};
```

But it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
error: underlying type 'PinName' of '<anonymous enum class>' must be an integral type
  enum class : PinName {
               ^
```

I also tried using `enum class : int {` but then the aliases are never in scope - I suspect I have to use plain `enum` instead. `enum : int` compiles, but then you can't pass any of the aliases to functions that take `PinName`. You get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'foo(<anonymous enum>, <anonymous enum>)'
 foo(PIN_SD_MISO, PIN_SD_MOSI);
     ^
```

(Candidate is `foo(PinName, PinName)`.)

Does anyone have any idea of a nice solution before I give up and use `const PinName PIN_SD_MISO = p2;`?

Comment: You could use macros?

Comment: True. Not sure I'd call that "nice"!

Comment: inheritance is not possible in enum classes. See also: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance)

Comment: maybe [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14508431/33499).

Comment: "`const PinName PIN_SD_MISO = p2;`" this is the right thing to do.

Comment: Would you consider providing a conversion function as a solution? It somehow defeats the purpose of a strongly typed `enum`.

Comment: @n.m. As I understand it the const thing would use memory, whereas an enum wouldn't.

Comment: @Wimmel Interesting, thanks! Probably not worth the complexity for me but nice link nonetheless.

Comment: "would use memory". Not necessarily. Make it static and check.

Comment: Yeah I guess it probably wouldn't - the optimiser should be fairly easily able to work out that I never takes its address or write to it. I guess it was just the principle of the thing! (Btw `static` would be unnecessary since all `const`s are implicitly `static`).

Comment: Have you tried using the scope resolution operator:  `PIN_SD_MOSI = PinName::p0`?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hacky but this is what I came up with if dealing with scoped enums:

```
enum class OriginalType {
   FOO,  // 0
   BAR   // 1
   END   // 2
};

enum class ExtendOriginalType : std::underlying_type_t<OriginalType> {
   EXTENDED_FOO = static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<OriginalType>>
                                           (OriginalType::END), // 2
   EXTENDED_BAR  // 3
};
```

and then use like:

```
OriginalType myOriginalType = (OriginalType)ExtendOriginalType::EXTENDED_BAR;
```

from [Base enum class inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance/54599684#54599684)

Comment: `OriginalType` is not an `enum class`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Elaborate?

Comment: In my question `PinName` is an `enum`, not an `enum class`, and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

I will be shot down for this, but why not just use macros?

```
#define PIN_SD_MOSI  p0
#define PIN_SD_MISO  p4
#define PIN_SD_SCK   p2
#define PIN_SD_CSN   p6
```

Comment: I did upvote you but actually, re-reading my question I did already mention this possibility (but using `const PinName PIN_SDMOSI = p2;` which is a better solution).

Comment: @Timmmm: why is it a better solution? Macros are simpler, after all.

Comment: It is properly typed and namespaced.

Comment: How about `inline constexpr PinName PIN_SD_MISO(){ return p2; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other "nice" solution besides a set of constants:

```
constexpr auto PIN_SD_MOSI = p0;
constexpr auto PIN_SD_MISO = p4,
constexpr auto PIN_SD_SCK = p2;
constexpr auto PIN_SD_CSN = p6;
```

You could also use another unscoped enum:

```
enum PinName2 {
    PIN_SD_MOSI = p0,
    PIN_SD_MISO = p4,
    PIN_SD_SCK = p2,
    PIN_SD_CSN = p6,
};
```

The "problem" with scoped enums is that they're their own type, and they don't implicit convert to the underlying type.