# About extending enum in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Suppose I have a base class with a method to return a state of its instance:

```
enum STATE {ALIVE, DEAD}

class BASE{
    virtual STATE doThingsAndReturnStatus() {...};
}
```

Now I have my derived class which may have additional state, e.g. `HALFDEAD`. It looks to me it is difficult to get the interface consistent unless for each derived class I need to add a STATE globally. (i.e. add new items into the definition of `STATE` in `class BASE`). My question is how to achieve this type of extending for derived class without touching on the based class or the file contains it.)

It is not necessary to restrict the discussion on "enum" only.

I found a related thread here. But it doesn't fit into my needs:

[Extending enums in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804840/extending-enums-in-c)

Comment: Once an enum is declared, that's it. If you want `HALFDEAD` as a member, you will need to declare that in the original enum. Alternatively, you could return a "lifeness", which is "alive = 100" and "dead = 0", and "halfdead = 50", and of course all the values in between can be used for more or less "halfway" (can of course use a scale 0..9, 0..100, floating point 0..1.0 or some other variation on the theme).

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish. This sounds suspiciously like an ill-advised [anti-]pattern, and the design probably needs to be rethought...

Comment: @twalberg Here is what I want to accomplish. I would like the class/instance do some stuff and then at the end return its status. But I would like the derived class could have its own status besides what base class has. I think my `virtual STATE getMyStatus()` is misleading. Will edit it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `enum` with an `int` or `string` or `float` or some such.

However, that is probably not a GREAT idea either. Assuming we COULD extend the `enum` [in an imaginary version of C++ that has this capability] , since `getMyStatus` is a virtual function, it is designed to be called from generic code that doesn't know the details of the derived classes. So if you write something like:

```
for(iter : baseClassContainter)
{
    status = iter->getMyStatus();
    switch(status)
    {
       case DEAD: 
            ... do some stuff here. 
            break;

       case ALIVE:
            ..... do some stuff here ... 

    }
}
```

What should this code do with "HALFDEAD"? It doesn't even know such a value exists, since [in our imaginary language that supports this] it only exists in the derived class...

Comment: I think my `virtual STATE getMyStatus()` is misleading. I changed it

Comment: Right, the point is that the calling function should be able to "use" the return value. If the base-class doesn't even recognise the value, how is it meaningful to return that value? It's bad design to have something that can be returend that isn't "useable" in the calling code. The point about inheritance is that base-class defines a protocol (or contract, if you like) of what goes in, and what comes out. You can't change that in the derived class. Either you add `HALFDEAD` to the original enum, or you can't return that value.

Answer (score 1):

You can get close with:

```
constexpr STATE HALFDEAD = static_cast<STATE>(DEAD+1);
```

But you're responsible for making sure the value (`DEAD+1` above) is not equal to any other enumerator.