# Plans for extendable Enums

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Thanks to C++11 we've got scoped and strong typed Enums.
But are there any plans to get this extendable too?

Something like this:

```
enum class OneTwoThree : char {one=1, two=2, three=3};
enum class Four : char {four=4} extends OneTwoThree;
```

Comment: As far as I know, not.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `enum class` declaration just says to forbid implicit conversions between enum values/integers/etc., it doesn't actually cause the enum to represent a complete type as it does in Java/Python/etc. Not to mention that the syntax for subclassing is already used to indicate underlying data type and `extends` is not a C++ keyword, and iirc the C++ standard committee does not like adding new keywords. If you really need a subclassable enumerated type in C++, you're better off using a template with variadic arguments, which will give you all the compile-time niceness of enums

Comment: @JAB: _Complete type_ has a specific meaning in C++, and **every** `enum` type is a _complete type_. `void` is an example of a type that is not complete.

Comment: @MSalters I knew that didn't feel like quite the right terminology. Complete/full/proper class or something?

Comment: @JAB: TO be honest, I have no idea what direction you're getting at. An `enum` isn't a class at all, and `enum class` doesn't change that. The choice of keywords is slightly unfortunate, but C++ avoids introducing new keywords.

Comment: @MSalters "An `enum` isn't a class at all, and `enum class` doesn't change that." That's the direction I was getting at, it just seems I worded it terribly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not appear so.

Nothing in C++ happens without a paper. Conveniently, you can view all of the papers online [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/), and follow along with more informal discussion in study groups for language evolution on the [official forums](https://isocpp.org/forums) (the "Future Proposals" group is probably the one you'd be interested in for changes to enumerations).

For the papers, a cursory search of the titles for papers back until 2011 reveals the following subject matter:

- [(N4266) Attributes for namespaces and enumerators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4266.html) - this concerns applying attribute specifiers to enumeration or namespace declarations.
- [(N4113) Reflection Type Traits For Classes, Unions and
  Enumerations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4113.pdf) - this proposes a series of type traits for doing compile-time inspection of enumeration list sizes as well as the names and values of enumeration items.
- [(N3815) Enumerator List Property Queries](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3815.html) - this is another proposal for effectively the same functionality as N4113.
- [(P0138R0) Construction Rules for enum class Values](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0138r0.pdf) - this discusses rules for conversions related to creating stronger "renamed integer" types.

None of these papers involve mechanisms for adding values to existing enumerations. Similarly, a cursory search for "enum" in the Future Proposals group yields of bunch of subjects, none of which appear to be about adding new values to an enumeration from somewhere other than the initial definition of the enumeration.

---

Several attempts have been made to implement this sort of functionality without library or language chagnes; [questions exploring the subject already exist on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804840/extending-enums-in-c), and might be useful reading for you.