# enum class in an Interface classe

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I have an interface class that looks like this

```
class Module {
public:

    virtual ~Module() = default;

    virtual void inc(CounterType, uint64_t) = 0;

    virtual void dec(CounterType, uint64_t) = 0;
};
```

and here the counterType is an enum class (from cpp11) . So the modules that are derived from my interface class shall use its own set of enum classe (which are again module specific)

and ofcourse the compiler is not ok with different modules using enum class other than the CounterType specified here.

Will I have to re design ? or What is the correct design practice in this case ?

Comment: What is `CounterType` representing?

Comment: How will you override methods with different signatures? That makes no sense. And is not allowed by the language.

Comment: I would suggest looking into using a templated class, but virtual templated member functions are illegal....

Comment: CounterType will be an enum to identify which counter for different modules
eg CounterMod1Type, CounterMod2Type ... etc. Each of these modules will have a variant of counter.

Comment: How do you intend to use the `Module` interface without knowing the type of `CounterType`?

Comment: _What is the correct design practice in this case?_  Prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Different enum classes would be fundamentally different variable types, and so this in a sense defies the purpose of virtual methods, which is intended to be used in cases where the signature is the same but the behavior is different depending on the instance type.

Since the enums associated with your different `Module`s are different the interfaces of these `Module`s should be different too, and thus `inc` and `dec` should not be virtual methods but rather methods with different signatures that each derived class of `Module` implements independently (or not at all, if appropriate).

If you want to do something like

```
void some_method(Module* module, CounterType* ctype, uint64_t value) {
    module->inc(*ctype, value);
}
```

then obviously NOT using a virtual method would not be a viable solution here and I don't have an answer regarding what alternative design decision would be appropriate simply because I do not have enough information regarding how `Module` is to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quiet the answer BUT:

The below link shows how the problem is solved in Java, there nothing much that can be done with c++

[Extending Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804840/extending-enums-in-c)

The solution I finally used : I made the Enums a template argument . Now I could create derived classes based on the Template values I gave