# How to extend enum inside the class

Tags: c++, enums

Is it possible to extend enum declared in a parent class?

Here are two classes:

```cpp
    class A {
        enum States {
            init,
            done
        }
    }

    class B : public A {
        enum States {
            // ???
            archived
        }
    }
```

I’d like to have a few extra states in class B. 
Is it possible? What’s the proper way?

Comment: Maybe `archived = A::States::done + 1`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending enums in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804840/extending-enums-in-c)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644629/base-enum-class-inheritance)

Comment: [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) can be used to hold 2 or more different enum types.

Comment: It is possible to declare constants of the same type as your enum, and extend it that way, but they don't have the same namespace relationship as, for example, c+=11 `enum class`. You need to also be aware that the compiler's storage of your enum depends on the range it's member values, so you should either specify the underlying type using c++11 syntax or declare an _MAX member when first declaring the enum.