# Enum extending with template parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, enums, parameter-pack

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16150/Inheriting-a-C-enum-type) is instruction to create enum extending behavior. I have implemented it like this:

*inheritenum.h*:

```cpp
    template <typename BaseEnumT, typename EnumT>
    class InheritEnum{
    public:
        InheritEnum() {}
        InheritEnum(EnumT e): enumt_(e){}
        InheritEnum(BaseEnumT e): baseEnum_(e){}
        explicit InheritEnum(int val): enumt_(static_cast<EnumT>(val)){}
        operator EnumT() const { return enumt_; }
    private:
        EnumT enumt_;
        BaseEnumT baseEnum_;
    };
```

Then in *main.cpp*:

```cpp
    enum class Fruit { apple, orange };
    enum class Drink { water, milk };
    typedef InheritEnum<Fruit, Drink> Eatable;
    void GetIt(Eatable eatable) {}
    int main(){
         GetIt(Fruit::apple);
    }
```

I can extend the behavior to inherit one more type like this

*inheritenum.h*

```cpp
    template <typename BaseEnumT, typename EnumT, typename EnumV>
    class InheritEnum{
    public:
        InheritEnum() {}
        InheritEnum(EnumT e): enumt_(e){}
        InheritEnum(EnumV e): enumv_(e){}
        InheritEnum(BaseEnumT e): baseEnum_(e){}
        explicit InheritEnum(int val): enumt_(static_cast<EnumT>(val)), enumv_(static_cast<EnumV>(val)){}
        operator EnumT() const { return enumt_; }
        operator EnumV() const { return enumv_; }
    private:
        EnumV enumv_;
        EnumT enumt_;
        BaseEnumT baseEnum_;
    };
```

And then in *main.cpp*:

```cpp
    enum class Fruit { apple, orange };
    enum class Drink { water, milk };
    enum class Food { pasta, fish };
    typedef InheritEnum<Fruit, Drink, Food> Eatable;
    void GetIt(Eatable eatable) {}
    int main(){
         GetIt(Food::fish);
    }
```

The question is how to use parameter pack here, instead of adding new types manually:

```cpp
    template <typename BaseEnumT, typename... EnumG>
    class InheritEnum{
        // how to modify the original code
    }
```

Comment: `std::variant<Enum1, Enum2, ..>`?

Comment: I think the term inheritance is kind of misleading in this case, as that's not really what the assignment seem to be about. Rather it's about *extending* existing enumerations and functions using them, to be able to handle a wider set of enumerations. Which also makes you use of it "wrong" as well, as you don't extend the `Fruit` enumeration with more fruits, but mix in different types of edible and drinkable things.Remember, inheritance is an "is-a" relationship, and `Drink` isn't a `Fruit` (or the opposite). It's (mostly) a terminology problem in the assignment itself.

Comment: @Jarod42 I am using C++ 11 and other friends also use some older version. `std::variant` is not supported there unfortunately.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree that it is more like extending enums, and not inheriting.

Comment: what you're having now looks more like a tuple. which behavior you want?

Comment: @appleapple `GetIt(Eatable eatable)` accept *Eatable* type and I can register some enums, and then pass the enum values there like `GetIt(Food::fish)`. So not any random enum value can be passed there. It provide some type safety there.

Comment: @AryanFirouzian I mean your implementation store all values, which is more like a tuple instead of variant

Comment: @AryanFirouzian (re: comment update) oh so the point is type safety. well since you cannot [query](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) [the](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/index) [type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) I don't really see it working though.

Comment: For the record, the code in the article you cite is broken. Formally, it exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an inactive member of the union. In practice, `consume(Orange)` would behave as `consume(Apple)`, since `Orange` and `Apple` both have the numeric value 0, and `InheritEnum` is basically a backhanded way of doing `reinterpret_cast<NewFruits>(Orange)`

Comment: How is `GetIt` expected to use `eatable`? How would it extract the actual enum value from which `eatable` was constructed?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes you are right. It turns out I cannot extract the right enum  :(

Comment: There are libraries which provide variant for C++11 as [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/variant.html).